# Odoo 10 POS, how to load sale orders from dB

Tags: javascript, odoo-10

Im extending the screen widget :

```
var ListSales = screens.ClientListScreenWidget.extend({ })
```

and im unable to d find code on how this gets sale orders from the DB, 
in other codes (like ClientListScreenWidget), there is no call to methods that fetch from the DB, just  filters like

```
get_product_by_category: function(category_id){
    var product_ids  = this.product_by_category_id[category_id];
    var list = [];
    if (product_ids) {
        for (var i = 0, len = Math.min(product_ids.length, this.limit); i < len; i++) {
            list.push(this.product_by_id[product_ids[i]]);
        }
    }
    return list;
},
```

where is the list of products actually  fetched from the DB? and how would i   fetch  something like sale orders?

Comment: load_server_data method into the point_of_sale/static/src/js/ is responsible to load all the data like products, users, partners etc. in the pos at the starting time.It actually calls the "read" method of models in py by using RPC calls.